# Network driver suddenly stopped working, cannot get IP from DHCP

Tags: networking, windows-10, router, bsod

### What happened:

I was browsing the internet normally and then suddenly I lost internet connection. Thinking nothing of it since I had to leave soon anyway I went to turn off my computer but for some reason it hang and I had to turn it off forcefully.

### What happens:

- Disabling/enabling the network adapter requires a restart to take effect.
- Shutting down takes a long time or causes the computer to restart if the network adapter is enabled, if it is disabled or disconnected it shuts down properly.
- ipconfig /renew and /release hang forever.

Once I came back, it was the same thing, no internet access. What I tried:

- Uninstalling/installing the network drivers. (Safe mode and normal)
- Clearing the TCP/IP stack.
- Changed power management to performance.
- Disabled the power management of the network adapter.
- Disabling the firewall and antivirus.
- Restarting the router.
- Defining a static IP address in the windows configuration and router settings.
- Installing the latest intel network drivers.

In one of the various restarts, a BSOD happened with the error code of  DRIVER_POWER_STATE_FAILURE, here is the crash dump for it:

Analysis of crash dump: https://hastebin.com/rahetuduko.md
Crash dump file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_4qF7TAsCYIekFhb3l2TUowR2c

It also seems that a few programs who try to use the network (Steam, chrome) get put into a state where they cannot be killed but still stay on the process list as active. Trying to kill them through the console results in the message:

```
Error: The process with PID xxxx could not be terminated.
Reason: There is no running instance of the task.
```

But another programs, Waterfox for example, don't have the same behaviour.

I honestly have run out of options and have no idea what to do anymore, the only option I have left is to format it. But it's something I really don't want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that all the cable connections of the main router were not working. There was another router connected to the main router that was being used as an access point and that one needed to be restarted.
Once that router was restarted all the other cable ports on the main router started working again.

Comment: as I also said on stackoverflow, update Wndows 10, you use an old patch level. also delete the memory.dmp now that it i no longer needed